# Sorting an (numerical) array based on (numerical) values of another (not the trivial way)?

Tags: php, arrays

Values of `$map` give the order:

```
$map = [
    'region_id'     =>  3,
    'province_id'   =>  4,
    'province_code' =>  5,
    'city_name'     => 11,
    'city_id'       =>  7,
    'is_lead'       => 13,
];
```

Subject of sorting:

```
$row = [
    3  => 1,
    4  => 1,
    5  => '001',
    7  => 1001,
    11 => 'Agliè',
    13 => 0,
];
```

Expected result:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 001
    [11] => Agliè
    [7] => 1001
    [13] => 0
)
```

### [ok] trivial solution creating a temporary array

```
$sorted = [];
foreach ($map as $i) {
    $sorted[$i] = $row[$i];
}
```

### [fail] using `+` operator

Doesn't work because values from `$row` will NOT override values in `$map`:

```
$sorted = array_flip($map) + $row;
print_r($sorted);

Array
(
    [3] => region_id
    [4] => province_id
    [5] => province_code
    [11] => city_name
    [7] => city_id
    [13] => is_lead
)
```

### [fail] using `array_merge`

Doesn't work because indexes are numerical:

```
$sorted = array_merge(array_flip($map), $row);
print_r($sorted);

Array
(
    [0] => region_id
    [1] => province_id
    [2] => province_code
    [3] => city_name
    [4] => city_id
    [5] => is_lead
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 001
    [9] => 1001
    [10] => Agliè
    [11] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can try this (simple way):

```
$sorted = [];
foreach ($map as $key => $i) {
    $sorted[$i] = $key;
}
ksort($sorted); //sort array by key
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$ordered = array();
foreach($map as $key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key,$row)) {
        $ordered[$key] = $row[$key];
        unset($row[$key]);
    }
}
return $ordered + $row;
```